# How to order a PHP multidimensional array by one of its subarray's key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a working delivery system that I need to present in alphabetical order sorted by the city, which is the key in a subarray.

This is the array:

```
array (
    'option_3' => array (
        'Rio' => '18',
    ),
    'option_4' => array (
        'Tokyo' => '20',
    ),
    'option_5' => array (
        'Berlim' => '23',
    )
)
```

And it is shown in this table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Bairro</th>
        <th>Valor</th>
        <th>Ação</th>
    </tr>


[a foreach goes here]

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $option_number;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $city;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $price;?></td>
        <td><button type='submit'>Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

This produces the folowing result:

```
ID  City  Value Action
3   Rio     18  Remover
4   Tokyo   20  Remover
5   Berlim  23  Remover
```

But I need it to be sorted by the city:

```
ID  City  Value Action
5   Berlim  23  Remover
3   Rio     18  Remover
4   Tokyo   20  Remover
```

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Comment: Firstly merge all option array and then sort the array. So you can use the array merge function and after that the you need to use the sort function. After that the result come that you want.

Answer (score 2):

You need to preserve the outer keys, use `uasort()`.  I prefer the spaceship (3-way comparison) operator between two `key()` calls.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/H3CT1))

```
$options = [
    'option_3' => [
        'Rio' => '18',
    ],
    'option_4' => [
        'Tokyo' => '20',
    ],
    'option_5' => [
        'Berlim' => '23',
    ]
];

uasort($options, function ($a, $b) {
    return key($a) <=> key($b);
});
var_export($options);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'option_5' => 
  array (
    'Berlim' => '23',
  ),
  'option_3' => 
  array (
    'Rio' => '18',
  ),
  'option_4' => 
  array (
    'Tokyo' => '20',
  ),
)
```

---

From PHP7.4+, You can use arrow syntax inside custom functions. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aEDoS))

```
uasort($options, fn($a, $b) => key($a) <=> key($b));
```

---

Preparing for an `array_multisort()` call is prohibitively hideous, IMO.  ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Gv7PV))

```
array_multisort(array_keys(array_merge(...array_values($options))), $options);
```

Comment: I still think the PHP7.4+ version looks more like hieroglyphics though!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, create a single array for each city and push them into a new array like that:

```
$options = [
    'option_3' => [
        'Rio' => '18',
    ],
    'option_4' => [
        'Tokyo' => '20',
    ],
    'option_5' => [
        'Berlim' => '23',
    ]
];

$newOptions = [];

foreach($options as $key => $option) {
    array_push($newOptions, [
        'id' => $key,
        'city' => key($option),
        'price' => reset($option)
    ]);
}
```

After, just sort it alphabetically by the value of each 'city' using `usort()`

```
usort($newOptions, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['city'], $b['city']);
});
```

Finally, you can simply do a foreach into `$newOptions` and echo whatever you want based on  keys 'id', 'city' and 'price'. Example:

```
foreach($newOptions as $option)

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $option['id'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $option['city']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $option['price']?></td>
    <td><button type='submit'>Remove</button></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this sort is little trickier as we need to preserve the parent key for each city as well. So, we go as follows:

- Modify the current array to have an extra parent_key in it's subarray which would look like:

  ```
  'option_3' => array (
      'Rio' => '18',
      'parent_key' => 'option_3'
  )
  ```
- Now, we use [usort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to compare the 2 subarrays via `name` through [strcmp()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) and return the result.
- We again iterate through them and use [array_keys()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to iterate over the data set. We do this as we are going to restore the parent key back without running into concurrent modification issue while iterating over the same array.

**Code:**

```
<?php

$data = array (
            'option_3' => array (
                'Rio' => '18',
            ),
            'option_4' => array (
                'Tokyo' => '20',
            ),
            'option_5' => array (
                'Berlim' => '23',
            )
        );


foreach($data as $key => &$value){
    $value['parent_key'] = $key;
}


usort($data,function($val1,$val2){
    $name1 = array_keys($val1)[0];
    $name2 = array_keys($val2)[0];
    return strcmp($name1,$name2); 
});

foreach(array_keys($data) as $index){
    $value = $data[$index];
    $parent_key = $value['parent_key'];
    unset($value['parent_key']); // unset parent key now as it is no longer needed
    $data[$parent_key] = $value;
    unset($data[$index]); // unset numeric index modified by usort()
}


print_r($data);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/q0YFk

**Update:** Current result does not hold extra keys like `city` etc, but it is easy to figure that out as a city name while doing a `foreach` in key-value fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that in many ways, here is my way [Demo](https://tehplayground.com/6jYUAjdksJ9rpYAv), hope it works for you.

```
$arr = array (
    'option_3' => array (
        'Rio' => '18',
    ),
    'option_4' => array (
        'Tokyo' => '20',
    ),
    'option_5' => array (
        'Berlim' => '23',
    )
);

$cities = [];

foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
    foreach($val as $key2=>$city){

        $option = explode('_', $key);
        $cities[$key2] = $city.'_'.$option[1];
    }
}
ksort($cities);

$res = [];
foreach($cities as $key=>$val){
    $temp = [];
    $temp['city'] = $key;
    $val_opt = explode('_', $val);
    $temp['value'] = $val_opt[0];
    $temp['option'] = $val_opt[1];

    $res[] = $temp;
}

print_r($res);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [city] => Berlim
            [value] => 23
            [option] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [city] => Rio
            [value] => 18
            [option] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [city] => Tokyo
            [value] => 20
            [option] => 4
        )

)
```